# Uploading a file to webservice and Downloading the file it returns

Tags: c#, webclient

Hi I am compressing a xml file using GZipStream and uploading it to a webservice which will return a gzipstream which I have to download. I have used the following method using WebClient in C# but it throws the Exception "WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations".

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
                    MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(data);
                    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                    GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress);
                    input.WriteTo(zip);
                    byte[] gzipStream = output.ToArray();
                    //Constructing Request
                    var postClient = new WebClient();
                    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                    postClient.UploadDataAsync(uri, gzipStream);
                    var resStream = new GZipStream(postClient.OpenRead(url),CompressionMode.Decompress);
                var reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
                var textResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return textResponse;
```

PLease help me in this.

Comment: Might be issue with UploadDataAsync()? try UploadData()

Comment: Are you sure you need to issue a GET request to the same URI _after_ performing a POST, or do you want to read the POST response?

Comment: After posting the gzip file to the Webservice, the service will procees the file and return another gzip file in response which I have download.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use *async* in this case:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
                MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(data);
                MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress);
                input.WriteTo(zip);
                byte[] gzipStream = output.ToArray();
                //Constructing Request
                var postClient = new WebClient();
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                postClient.UploadData(uri, gzipStream);
                var resStream = new GZipStream(postClient.OpenRead(url),CompressionMode.Decompress);
            var reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
            var textResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return textResponse;
```

Or you should *await* the *async* operation (if your method is *async*):

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
                MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(data);
                MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress);
                input.WriteTo(zip);
                byte[] gzipStream = output.ToArray();
                //Constructing Request
                var postClient = new WebClient();
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                await postClient.UploadDataAsync(uri, gzipStream);
                var resStream = new GZipStream(postClient.OpenRead(url),CompressionMode.Decompress);
            var reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
            var textResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return textResponse;
```